# Heroku suspended my app and I can't find why

Tags: heroku

I received this email and my example app is now gone and wont 'wake up' by hitting the url.

> Hello,
>
> This is a notice to inform you that your Heroku app, url2go, has been
> suspended.
> **If you believe this app has been suspended in error, please open a support ticket at https://help.heroku.com**
>
> The Heroku Team https://heroku.com

Followed the email's suggestion and tried to open a support ticket but because it's free tier I got sent here.  Has anyone had this issue and were did you find the reason for the suspension?

The app is not a bot, it doesn't have any use other than to show I could build simple url shortener in rails.  It actually stays dormant 99% of the year.

I feel like that email is as opaque as an undocumented database trigger. Even on the dashboard everything looks ok, until I click Open App, 404.

I don't mind taking down the app if it trespasses any coding rules or restriction, I would like to know and have the opportunity to fix it though.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Salesforce Stack Exchange is a community knowledge base; unfortunately, we cannot help with matters of Heroku policy or enforcement as we have no access to those internal systems.

Comment: Yeah it seems I am out of luck. Terrible from heroku though, no ticket for free dynos, that's understandable, but then why the vague email. I have no way to know unless I upgrade the tier.   Guess the demo will stay down.   Thanks for your reply David.

Comment: That's weird. I have a bunch of stuff that's running on free dynos, I've never seen this before. If I had to guess, though, you probably "accidentally" (whatever that means) got linked to an adult website or something. I'd have to read the terms to find out exactly what could have happened (like any of us read terms...).

Comment: @sfdcfox you might be on to something. it was a publicly available url shortener so someone might have abused it. I wonder if I can still connect to the postgres to check the raw data.  I would have liked for heroku to just tell me that was it. Or if it was a link to a blacklisted domain (due to malware).